# centos creating a second alias for my web address

Tags: centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [third level domain and debian](https://serverfault.com/questions/454349/third-level-domain-and-debian)

How can I go about having another alias for my web address, what i mean is, if to get to a website on my centos server i can go to domain.com for example, how can i make it so something like x.domain.com will also work as an address to my website, i want to use a VirtualHost to later make that second address land on a different index page...any help is appriciated

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/454349/third-level-domain-and-debian

Comment: @lain where can I check how to change the DNS settings so x.domain.com resolves to my server?

Comment: That would very much depend on how your DNS is managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time being, you can use the 'ServerAlias' directive in your current VirtualHost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias x.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /path/to/web/dir
</VirtualHost>
```

Then later on, you can configure a new VirtualHost for x.domain.com to point to a new documentroot.